# UNNotificationServiceExtension didRecieve not called

Tags: ios, swift, unnotificationserviceextension

I have added mutable-content: 1 in apns payload. Checked the deployment target as well. Still I am not getting call in didRecieve method.
I am using XCode 12

NOTE: UNNotificationContentExtension is working but not service

Comment: Are you usind didreceiverRemoteNotification method with fetchCompletionHandler or normal userInfo only?  Can you add some code here?

Comment: I am getting callback in didRecieveRemoteNotification but not in  service extension

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting delegate methods to self in application Launching Option Method.